# How can I constrain the apriori function in R to consider only specific value items in LHS?

Tags: r, data-mining, apriori, arules

In R, I am trying to use the apriori function for Association Rule Learning.

I have a data set like this:

```
A B C D E 

1 0 0 1 0

1 0 1 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

0 0 0 1 0
```

I am interested in cases where `E = 1`, which I can get by doing:

```
inspect( subset( rules.sorted, subset = rhs %pin% "E=1" ))
```

But I am also interested in cases only where the `LHS` contains `'=1'` conditions and not `'=0'`.

So, I don't want rules like:

```
{A=1,D=0} => {E=1}
```

I just want rules like

```
{A=1,C=1} => {E=1}
```

How can I achieve this in the `LHS` side? I could only gather how to constraint it to look for rules in specific column(s), but not for any column with specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  The issue arises when you convert your data to a factor (like a couple people mentioned in the comments to another answer).  When I converted my data.frame to a matrix and then to transactions, I had positive rules only in the output.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying that, but converting data frame to matrix would mean I lose all my variable names. How do you handle that? Because I have hundreds of variables.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noted, if you want `E=1` on the right hand side, just *filter your data*.

By default, association rule mining should give you only positive rules, aka `A => B`.

Usually, if you wanted to have negative rules, you would have to add negated symbols to your data, i.e. `ANOT=1` when `A=0`.

Are you sure that you aren't just *misinterpreting* the output?

Comment: Hi 
I do get negative rules as well, for example in the above case, something like:
{D=0} => {E=1}.
These '=0' parts on lhs are rules I would like to avoid. I am using apriori for first time but I read about it from different places. I never came across that association rules give only positive rules. Are you referring to the R function apriori? Or is it that the software/function you use excludes such negative rules by default?

Comment: Original APRIORI did not do that as far as I know. Have you checked options to your implementation? I don't use R, so I don't have the manual. It may also be part of the data transformation R does to produce itemsets... I.e. it doesn't treat "1" as present and "0" as not present, but "A=1" and "A=0" as two _different_ items.

Comment: Yes, I checked the options. I couldn't find such an option to control the equality value. The function required my data to be of class factor. So, I too think R is treating the 0's and 1's as two different items. I never thought fixing that could fix my problem. I will try to fix it and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using different software, too. I believe this is a good FIM software page: http://www.borgelt.net/fpm.html - I'm not a fan of R, quality varies too much.

Comment: That's a great link. Thanks.